# Unit test databinding in angular directive with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, data-binding

I'm trying to unit test the databinding in a very simple angular directive:

Directive

```
<uri></uri>

.directive('uri', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/directives/uri.html',
        transclude: false,
        replace: false,
        scope: false,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.uri = null;
        }
    };
});
```

Template

```
<h2>url</h2>
<input type="text" placeholder="{{uri}}" class="form-control" ng-readonly="true">
```

Unit Test

```
describe('Directive: uri', function () {

    // we declare some global vars to be used in the tests
    var elem,
        scope,
        $compile,
        directive = angular.element('<uri></uri>'),
        template = 'views/partials/directives/uri.html';

    // load the module / template we want to test
    beforeEach(module('app', template));

    // before each test, creates a fresh scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_, $templateCache) {
        //assign the template to the expected url called by the directive and put it in the cache
        var tplCache = $templateCache.get(template);
        $templateCache.put(template, tplCache);
        console.log(tplCache);

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
    }));

    function compileDirective() {
        //create the element with the directive template
        elem = $compile(directive)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }

    it('should set the input value to the scope.uri value', function () {
        // add uri to scope
        var uri = 'test-uri';
        scope.uri = uri;
        // then produce our directive using it
        console.log(scope.uri);
        compileDirective();
        console.log(scope.uri);
        console.log(elem);
        // this should impact the input value value
        var templateAsHtml = elem.html();
        expect(templateAsHtml).toContain(scope.uri);
    });
});
```

The templateCache caches the template. 
The element gets compiled on the scope with the supplied directive.
But somehow the uri property is not linked to my directive. Also, after the scope.$digest()
the scope.uri is null...

Karma test results

```
LOG: '<h2>url</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{uri}}" ng-readonly="true">'
LOG: 'test-uri'
LOG: null
LOG: Object{0: <uri class="ng-scope"><h2>url</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-readonly="true" readonly="readonly"></uri>, length: 1}

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) Directive: uri should set the input value to the scope.uri value FAILED
    Expected '<h2>url</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-readonly="true" readonly="readonly">' to contain null.

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.03 secs / 0.026 secs)

Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Can you include your directive definition please?

Comment: Well, thanks Cathal... You see, my directive initializes with a uri = null. That overwrites my test in the digest loop. doh...

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake: My directive initializes with a $scope.uri = null. That overwrites my test in the digest loop.

Directive:

```
.directive('uri', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/directives/uri.html',
        transclude: false,
        replace: false,
        scope: false,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.uri = null;
        }
    };
});
```

Fixed unit test with re-applying the new value to the scope:

```
it('should set the input value to the scope.uri value', function () {
    // produce our directive
    compileDirective();
    // add uri to scope
    var uri = 'test-uri';
    scope.uri = uri;
    scope.$digest();
    // check the html
    var templateAsHtml = elem.html();
    expect(templateAsHtml).toContain(uri);
});
```